# Valums multi file uploading

Tags: javascript, vb.net, upload

I am using Valums AJAX javascript, found at http://valums.com/ajax-upload/
I am using VB.net as my server side scripting language and I have a webservice that is called, but I do not know how to retrieve the query string sent by his code.  Can some help me?

Comment: can you post the code you have for your javascript?  I don't know anything about vb.net, so that i cannot help out with. nor have i ever used this script before.

Comment: $(document).ready(function () {
            var uploader = new qq.FileUploader({
                // pass the dom node (ex. $(selector)[0] for jQuery users)
                element: document.getElementById('file-uploader'),
                // path to server-side upload script
                action: 'WebService.asmx/NewSong'
            });
        });         //end ready()

Answer (score 1, accepted):

looks like you have access to these methods:

```
onSubmit: function(id, fileName){},
onProgress: function(id, fileName, loaded, total){},
onComplete: function(id, fileName, responseJSON){},
onCancel: function(id, fileName){},
```

I would imagine that the `onComplete` method is what you would most likely want if you wanted to show something once the entire process was done.  I would guess the `responseJSON` value is what you would most likely want to check.